# Thread doesn't recognize change in a flag

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I Work with couple of threads. all running as long as an exit_flag is set to false.

I Have specific thread that doesn't recognize the change in the flag, and therefor not ending and freeing up its resources, and i'm trying to understand why.

**UPDATE:** After debugging a bit with gdb, i can see that given 'enough time' the problematic thread does detects the flag change.
My conclusion from this is that not enough time passes for the thread to detect the change in normal run.

How can i 'delay' my main thread, long enough for all threads to detect the flag change, without having to JOIN them? (the use of `exit_flag` was in an intention NOT to join the threads, as i don't want to manage all threads id's for that - i'm just detaching each one of them, except the thread that handles input).
I've tried using `sleep(5)` in `close_server()` method, after the flag changing, with no luck

Notes:

1. Other threads that loop on the **same** flag does terminate succesfully
2. exit_flag declaration is: `static volatile bool exit_flag`
3. All threads are **reading** the flag, flag value is changed only in `close_server()` method i have (which does only that)
4. Data race that may occur when a thread reads the flag just before its changed, doesn't matter to me, as long as in the next iteration of the while loop it will read the correct value.
5. No error occurs in the thread itself (according to strerr & stdout which are 'clean' from error messages (for the errors i handle in the thread)
6. Ths situation also occurs even when commenting out the entire `while((!exit_flag) && (remain_data > 0))` code block - so this is not a `sendfile` hanging issure

`station_info_t` struct:

```
typedef struct station_info {
    int socket_fd;
    int station_num;
} station_info_t;
```

Problematic thread code:

```
void * station_handler(void * arg_p)
{
    status_type_t rs = SUCCESS;

    station_info_t * info = (station_info_t *)arg_p;
    int remain_data = 0;
    int sent_bytes = 0;
    int song_fd = 0;
    off_t offset = 0;
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    struct stat file_stat;

    /* validate station number for this handler */
    if(info->station_num < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "station_handler() station_num = %d, something's very wrong! exiting\n", info->station_num);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Open the file to send, and get his stats */
    fp = fopen(srv_params.songs_names[info->station_num], "r");

    if(NULL == fp) {
        close(info->socket_fd);
        free(info);
        error_and_exit("fopen() failed! errno = ", errno);
    }

    song_fd = fileno(fp);

    if( fstat(song_fd, &file_stat) ) {
        close(info->socket_fd);
        fclose(fp);
        free(info);
        error_and_exit("fstat() failed! errno = ", errno);
    }

    /** Run as long as no exit procedure was initiated */
    while( !exit_flag ) {
        offset = 0;
        remain_data = file_stat.st_size;

        while( (!exit_flag) && (remain_data > 0) ) {
            sent_bytes = sendfile(info->socket_fd, song_fd, &offset, SEND_BUF);
            if(sent_bytes < 0 ) {
                error_and_exit("sendfile() failed! errno = ", errno);
            }

            remain_data = remain_data - sent_bytes;
            usleep(USLEEP_TIME);
        }
    }

    printf("Station %d handle exited\n", info->station_num);

    /* Free \ close all resources */
    close(info->socket_fd);
    fclose(fp);
    free(info);
    return NULL;
}
```

I'll be glad to get some help.
Thanks guys

Comment: 1) Yoda conditions not use you should. 2) Don't use homebrew boolean types/constants. C provides a standard boolean type and constants in `stdbool.h` 3) Comparing a boolean flag with a constant is a bad idea, as it is more complicated to read/understand. Instead name the flag properly and just test it.

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for your comment. i didn't understood number 1 in your list - please elaborate if you can :) regarding number 2 - i'll check this, thank you. **EDIT**: changed to `bool` flag as suggested, didn't have any impact on my issue

Comment: Don't you have a search provider available (IOW: is google not available)? And please take the [tour]. Comments are not for answering, but ask for clarification and to provide additional useful information.

Comment: What if `sendfile` hangs? Have you tried to strace/gdb your hung thread?

Comment: Yoda conditions all bad are not.  Do you really need this thread to exit cleanly, ie. are you terminating the whole process or not?

Comment: @Olaf, i DID asked for a clarification regarding your first bullet.
@nsilent22,i'm not sure `sendfile` can hang, couldn't find a conclusive answer opon searching. i'll try strace/gdb my thread .
@MartinJames, yes, i do need the thread to exit cleanly (whole process is terminating). thanks

Comment: @Adiel: One comment per addressee! Don't YELL at me. I just told you to google. `Yoda conditions` is a well known phrase.

Comment: @Adiel if the whole process is terminating, do you REALLY need the thread to exit cleanly?  I suspect premature stoptimization...

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: in each place where this expression is used: `(FALSE == exit_flag)`  the literal `FALSE` is not defined.  suggest replacing each such expression with: `(!exit_flag)`

Comment: to properly debug this problem, we need the definition of `struct station_info_t`.  Please post as an edit to your question.

Comment: in general, error messages should be sent to stderr, not stdout.   so suggest replacing calls to `printf()` for error messages with: `fprintf( stderr, ....)`

Comment: when referencing errno, the reference needs to be immediately after the call to the system function that set the errno variable. there is no guarantee that  `close()` and/or `fclose()` and/or `free()` hasn't modified that value. Suggest eliminate the error_and_exit() function and call perror() then cleanup, then call exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

Comment: to keep things consistent, the main thread must not exit until all the sub threads have exited.  In general this means the main thread call `pthread_join()` for each sub thread `ID` before the main thread exits.

Comment: @Olaf, i wasn't yelling, that's just a misunderstanding - i'm not familiar with star wars movies (havn't seen them) therefore i didn't understood your entire 1st bullet, not just the yoda conditions phrase. sorry if you got the wrong idea from my comment. BTW, main post updated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as stated by **user362924** the main issue is that i don't join the threads in my main thread, therefore not allowing them enough time to exit.

A workaround to the matter, if for some reason one wouldn't want to join all threads and dynamically manage thread id's, is to use `sleep` command in the end of the main thread, for a couple of seconds.

of course this workaround is not good practice and not recommended (to anyone who gets here by google)